# Scroll down button not working in Webflow

Tags: css, scroll, hyperlink, webflow

I'm trying to link scroll down button to the next section of my site in Webflow. I've used a link block to achieve the same. I have also used a code for snap scrolling of my site's various sections. The scroll down button however is not working and landing to the next section of the page. I have also created section ID to link the button, nothing seems to be working. Is there any solution for this? TIA

**Here's the code I had used for snap scrolling:**

```
<style>
.scroll-snap-wrapper {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
.section-1 {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Web flow provides a way to scroll automatically to anchors (meaning ID’s of elements).
First, give an element that you want to be scrolled to as an anchor by giving it an ID. You can do that in the “Element Settings Panel (d)”, Now you can select that element as a target in the link settings of any link text or link block. If that link is clicked, the page scrolls to the top of that element!
You can only select anchors on that very same page!

Try implementing this first, without using the smooth scroll, this library overrides the browsers viewport position constantly.
Also, you are importing two different scrolling libraries, I’m not sure this is intentional? It seems they don’t work very nice together, try only using one.